# Remove consecutive commas with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I use

```
str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, '')
```

to remove leading and trailing commas.

How can I extend it so I also remove two consecutive commas?

So `,some text,,more text,` should become `some text,more text`?

One way would be to chain with

```
str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, '').replace(/,,/g, ',')
```

but then `,some text,,,,more text,` will become `some text,,more text` instead of `some text,more text`.

Comment: Since you appear to be `.split(',')`-ing the resulting string, I've written an answer that easily works around the extra commas, immediately returning the split string you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to be using the `str` [as a source for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124849/remove-consecutive-commas-with-regex#comment67520000_40124899), you can replace all the `.replace` calls with:

```js
var str = ",some text,,,,more text,";

var resultArray = str.split(',') // Just split the string.
  .filter(function(item){        // Then filter out empty items
    return item !== '';
  });

console.log(resultArray)
```

No need to worry about leading, trailing or double comma's.

Comment: Downvoter: sure, this is not _exactly_ what the question asks, but this is what the OP is doing with his string, as seen in the linked comment. This is fixing 2 problems in 1 go.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the leading and trailing commas, and then replace multiple consecutive commas by single comma

```
str.replace(/^,|,$|(,)+/g, '$1');
```

`,+` will match one or more comma, `g`-global flag to replace all occurrences of it.

```js
var str = ',some text,,more text,';

str = str.replace(/^,|,$|(,)+/g, '$1');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Great thanks. Now I use `str.replace(/^,|,$/g, '').replace(/,+/g, ',').split(',')`. Would it be better to use the regex to split by commas instead of first modifying the string and then splitting by comma?

Comment: @Tushar Hi.. I have an dependency injection problem in Angularjs. Let me know when you come online..

Answer (score 3):

You may add an alternative branch and enclose it with a capturing group and then use a replace callback method where you can analyze the match groups and perform the replacement accordingly:

```js
var s = ',some text,,,,more text,';
var res = s.replace(/^,|,$|(,+)/g, function(m,g1) {
  return g1 ? ',' : '';
});
console.log(res);
```

To split with commas and get no empty entries in the resulting array, use a simple

```js
console.log(',some text,,,,more text,'.split(',').filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: See my one-liner update to obtain an array of non-empty elements with `.split(',').filter(Boolean)`, no regex required.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor Stribiżew, this one is a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a positive lookahead with another comma.

```js
var str = ',some text,,more text,';

str = str.replace(/^,|,$|,(?=,)/g, '')

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about one replace only like: `",some text,,,,more text,".replace(/(^,)|(,$)|,(?=,)/g, '');`

**[EDIT]**

> Note that lookbehinds don't work in javascript. so you can only use a lookahead like so.